# Getting "cannot resolve symbol Gravity" error while trying to center TextView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set text to center programmatically, but I cannot find how to import this particular symbol anywhere- `Gravity.CENTER`

```
textOut.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

> cannot resolve symbol Gravity

It is frustrating having to go on Google and search for every missing symbol.
In C++ at a header would include all the necessary definitions for a particular API or set of classes, so only searching for 1 header include is usually enough,

In Java I have to search for 10-20 different imports at a time when using snippets of code found online

Is there an easy way to find the correct imports in cases like this?
Doing a google search for "import for Gravity.CENTER" does not produce any useful results.

How do Java programmers deal with these issues? Is there a directory where I can look up Symbols and their necessary imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're using Android Studio** you can hover with your cursor on the symbol to import and just import the class. However this is not usually necessary, because Android studio will automatically add the needed import for you

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Edit

Also **Java's extension for VSCode** has this kind of functionality as I can remember... If you're not using none of those search those funcionality for your tools

Answer (score 0):

```java
import android.view.Gravity;
```

[Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity).